# PDO run LIKE query for multiple table columns for a single string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use like on two columns in my table now.

tablename = `roomnames`

table columns = `roomID`, `roomName`, `roomNo`

i have an input field which sends a string value on which the query should execute.

Here below is the PHP PDO code

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: HaiderHassan
 * Date: 9/3/14
 * Time: 9:52 PM
 */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=houserentsystem;charset=utf8', 'root', 'admin');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
if($_POST['searchFilter']){
    $searchFilter = $_POST['searchFilter'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE ? OR roomNo LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%'));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    print_r(json_encode($results));
}
```

the query i tried is wrong and not working here is what i tried now.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE ? OR roomNo LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%'));
```

i want if i search room No or roomName, it will show me result if that room number or room name is present in the table of database.

Sorry for my bad English. I hope i have explained.
i want to search in multiple columns for a table against a input string, Input string can be a no or name.
Number is for roomNo and name for room name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got to have a value for every parameter, so double your searchfilter in the array of the values for the parameters:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE ? OR roomNo LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%','%'.$searchFilter.'%' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `MATCH` struct from MySQL:

```
SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE MATCH (roomName, roomNo IN BOOLEAN MODE) AGAINST(?)
```

The params needed inside `AGAINST(?)` Would then go as an array inside `$stmt->execute(...)`

For further information, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match).

[Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html):

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6
>   and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes
>   can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> The `IN BOOLEAN MODE` prevents from searching only by words, but by
>   string.

Comment: problem solve with @VMai query,
But i also tried your query and its not working.

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE MATCH (?, ?) AGAINST ('houserentsystem')");
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%','%'.$searchFilter.'%' ));` not working.

Comment: @SizzlingCode Sry to hear that, I edited my answer. It's all about the query, not the PDO, Glad to hear that an answer helped you. And your title says "multiple tables", that's why I put the `MATCH` thing...

Comment: It should be `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName, roomNo FROM roomnames WHERE MATCH (roomName, roomNo) AGAINST (?)");`, I think. But the problem with fulltext search is that it searches words by default.

Comment: Please have a look at my suggestion: the columns to be searched go into the MATCH clause, the search term into AGAINST. We know the two columns to be sarched: `roomName` and `roomNo`.

Comment: Thankyou again, it was nice info.
i am using InnoDB, utf-8 bin